# "App not installed"apk not updating with aab

Tags: android, apk, android-app-bundle

I have extracted apk from aab. I was able to install the apk on real Android device but the issue comes when a older apk already present and then if I try to update it by installing the apk(extracted from aab), its givng "App not installed" error.

Comment: **How** exactly are you attempting to install it?

Comment: I don't know what the reason is but you can always uninstall and then install again